# locate javascript object in my code that heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory

so here is the error I got after I run a node program for around 10 mins.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

  186465 ms: Mark-sweep 1788.2 (4117.3) -> 1787.6 (4128.3) MB, 275.4 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  186782 ms: Mark-sweep 1787.6 (4128.3) -> 1787.3 (4130.3) MB, 316.6 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  187141 ms: Mark-sweep 1787.3 (4130.3) -> 1811.6 (4099.3) MB, 358.8 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
  187450 ms: Mark-sweep 1811.6 (4099.3) -> 1836.3 (4099.3) MB, 309.5 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0xc0338acfb51 <JS Object>
    1: parse [native json.js:~61] [pc=0xb9af5c3b3e1] (this=0xc0338ac9111 <a JSON with map 0x26b709e0a0e1>,C=0x16719f063189 <Very long string[13958430]>,w=0xc0338a04381 <undefined>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 1->2
    3: onreadystatechange [/Users/harryfeng/Documents/javascriptKitchen-Sink/node_modules/parse/lib/node/RESTController.js:110] [pc=0xb9af5c64295] (this=0x26c045d78981 <JS Object>)...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::Runtime_ParseJson(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0xb9af52092a7
Abort trap: 6
```

I know it is the memory problem but this line:

```
Security context: 0xc0338acfb51 <JS Object>
```

is it possible to locate what object causing the problem? it there a software that can help me locate this object in my code so that I know how to fixed it?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I used [heapdump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heapdump) to write the heap dump into a file for later analysis - it can be loaded into Chrome dev tools.

If you know the size of heap when the app crashes, you can use `process.memoryUsage().heapUsed` to monitor the current size so that you can create the heapdump a while before it reaches the crash threshold.